# Beamer Overlays within a tikz node has growing indent

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, indentation, overlays, only

I am using beamer overlays within tikz nodes, which yields the 
expected result, except for a growing indent.

Here is a minimalistic example showing the behaviour.

```latex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path[draw] (1,0) -- (1,2);
    \node [text width=3cm, anchor=west] at (1,1) {
      \only<1>{Here}
      \only<2>{There}
      \only<3>{Away}
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in the text moving across the slides:

[image: Example]

I did not expect or intend this. Any help towards avoiding this behaviour is appreciated.

Comment: Place `%` at the end of the lines inside the node, else you have a parasitic space for each line ending.

Comment: You are absolutely right. This resolves the issue.

Comment: @Skillmon an answer...? :)

Comment: @cmhughes most likely we'll find a dupe if we search for it, so no, I don't think this should get an answer.